# Cannot append to an array outside of function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a REST API to input the some values into a DB. The mysql query function runs fine and the values populate in the DB. However, when attempting to respond with a message that contains `client_response.data`, it contains an empty array.

When placing the console.log in the arrow function inside `db.query()` it returns the populated array.

```
try {
    const client_response = {}
    client_response.data = []

    function Record_response_data(obj_id, partner_id, tech) {
        this.id = obj_id, 
        this.partner_id = partner_id,
        this.tech = tech
    }

    try {
        var request = req.body.data.partners
        for(const record of request) {
            const a1 = db.query("INSERT INTO partners (partner_id, tech) VALUES (?, ?)",
            [record.partner_id.toUpperCase(), record.tech],
            (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    var resource = new Record_response_data(null, record.partner_id, record.tech)
                    client_response.data.push(record_header)
                } else {
                    var resource = new Record_response_data(result.insertId, record.partner_id, record.tech)
                    client_response.data.push(record_header)
                }
            }
            );
        }
    } catch(err) {
        ...
    }
    console.log(client_response.data) // result is []
} catch(err) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: does `db.query` return a Promise? If not, then your `await` is meaningless - nothing to do with scope, more to do with incorrect handling of asynchrony

Comment: I just removed `await` and I'm still experiencing the same issue

Comment: of course, because you're still not handling asynchrony ... `await` was completely superfluous, so removing it won't fix anything - some versions of `db.query` do return a promise if you do not supply a callback function - then you can await the result of db.query, and your code should then possibly work - i.e. `const result = db.query(.....)` with no callback - but you'll need a nested try/catch to handle the "error" which apparently isn't an error

Answer (score 0):

if `db.query` returns a Promise when called without a callback, this should work - some `db` libraries work that way, i.e. with a callback, the function returns `undefined`, without a callback, the function returns a `Promise`

And since `async`/`await` **only** awaits Promises, you need a `Promise` to successfully `await` the result

Note: `await` will work with any return type - however, it won't wait for just any asynchronous code - the power of `await` is that if the returned value is a Promise, `await` will (seemingly - not actually) *pause* execution of the current function until the `Promise` it is `await`ing resolves (in other words, is fulfilled or rejected)

The reason you often wrap an `await` inside a try/then block is, a `rejected` Promise throws as an error, which you then handle in the catch block

```
const client_response = {};
client_response.data = [];

function Record_response_data(obj_id, partner_id, tech) {
    this.id = obj_id, 
    this.partner_id = partner_id,
    this.tech = tech
}

var request = req.body.data.partners;
for(const record of request) {
    try {
        const result = await db.query("INSERT INTO partners (partner_id, tech) VALUES (?, ?)",[record.partner_id.toUpperCase(), record.tech]);
        var resource = new Record_response_data(result.insertId, record.partner_id, record.tech)
        client_response.data.push(record_header);
    } catch (err) {
            var resource = new Record_response_data(null, record.partner_id, record.tech)
            client_response.data.push(record_header);
    }
}
console.log(client_response.data); // result is []
```

alternatively, if there is a promise based "version" of this `db.query`, (for whatever db + library you are using) use that one in the above code